# React router не работает

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Основной компонент:

```
render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="wrapper">
                {document.URL !== 'http://localhost:3000/auth/login' ?
                    <Header state={this.props} />
                    :
                    ''}
                <div className="main-panel">
                    <div className="content">
                        <Main state={this.props} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Роутер:

```
export default class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        // console.log('main ', this.props.state)
        return (

                <main>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route  exact  path="/brokers/customers/list/:project/:type/:active"  render={()=><CustomersList state={this.props.state}/>} />
                        <Route path="/brokers/customers/create/:project" render={()=><CustomerCreate state={this.props.state}/>} />

                        <Route path="/auth/login" component={Login} />
                    </Switch>
                </main>

        )
    }
}
```

Пример ссылки:

```
<Link to={`/brokers/customers/create/${project.id}`}
                       className="btn btn-xs btn-white btn-round material-icon_success">
                        <i className="material-icons">note_add</i>
                        Create
                    </Link>
```

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'))
```

При нажатии меняется адрес в браузере но не переходит на другой компонент, переходит только по нажатии enter

Comment: А ты используешь `connect()`? Он переопределяет некоторые методы в компоненте. Я вынес роутер в отдельный компонент, и все заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Пока что нашел только такое решение:

```
 <NavLink to={`/${getPart()}/customers/list`}  onClick={() => this.changeType(1)}>
                                <i className="material-icons material-icon_success">assignment_returned</i>&nbsp;
                                <span>LEAD</span>
                            </NavLink>
```

Вызвать экшн вместе с переходом по ссылке